# Java regular expression check for string containing web addres

Tags: java, regex

I have string pattern, like below:

```
String wwwPattern = "^(.*[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+.*)$";
```

When I try this pattern to match with string I observed something like this:

```
String string1 = "www.stackoverflow.com";
System.out.println(string1.matches(wwwPattern)); // print true, this is OK

String string2 = "test www.stackoverflow.com test";
System.out.println(string2.matches(wwwPattern)); // print true, this is OK

String string3 = "test \r\n www.stackoverflow.com test";
System.out.println(string3.matches(wwwPattern)); //print false
```

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: You will fail to match valid hostnames, and match invalid hostnames with this regex

Comment: Yes I see, but I want to know why pattern fails when string contains '\r\n'. The problem came with dot and next line characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to match line breaks with the `.`.

To use it inline instead of as an `int` flag, use `(?s)`.

**Example**

```
String pattern = "(?s)^(.*[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+.*)$";
String input = "test \r\n www.stackoverflow.com test";
System.out.println(input.matches(pattern));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Also I would move the outer parenthesis after the `.*` (first and last), so you match your content in group 1.

Something like: `"(?s)^.*([a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+).*$"`

Finally, take a look at fge's comment (+1).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a couple of problems here.

First, ".*" will not match newline characters. Second, using String.matches() will only return true if the entire string matches the pattern.

You may want to try using Pattern and Matcher like so if you just want to find any match in the string.

```
String wwwPattern = ".*([a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+).*";
String stringTest = "test \r\n www.stackoverflow.com test";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(wwwPattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringTest);
System.out.println(m.find()); //print true
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your regexp starts with ^ and ends with $, so: it's like saying "find something like xxx.yyyy.zzz before an end of line"</s>  UPDATE: Thanks for the comments

```
"test \r\n www.stackoverflow.com test"
```

becomes `"test \r"`  (first line) and `"\n www.stackoverflow.com test"` (second line)

The first part does not match because it does not have two dots with letters before and after before the end of line, and `.` (regex metacharacter) does not match with end of line unless [**you explicit that**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) (adding `?s` to your regexp).

Comment: But he has .*s either side to match anything on either side of the url

Comment: @OGHaza I added the explanation: it does not match with end of lines

Comment: Yup but the rest of your answer is incorrect, unless the appropriate flag is set `(?m)`, `^$` match start and end of input, not the line.

Comment: You're right. I was mixing up the fact that ^ means "start of a line" and $ "end of line" with the dots issue.